# Desktop Firefox on Android

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android

Is it possible to run the full desktop Firefox on Android somehow?

Since the UI rewrite, Firefox Mobile is lacking quite a few features and is really bad to use on a device with a bigger screen (tablet), since they completely scrapped the tablet UI.

I don't really want to have it running in a Linux container (which I already have), but recompiled natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if Android bases on Linux and theoretically could be able to execute the ARM v7/v8 version of Mozilla Firefox for Linux
there are multiple problems:

1. the libraries available on Linux and Android differs a lot
2. The whole UI system on Linux using Wayland/X-Window manager is non-existent on Android. So Firefox would be unable to present you an user interface nor render web pages to the screen.

Especially the second point explains why you can run Desktop Mozilla Firefox in some sort of container but not directly on Android.